# text-decoration transition not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

As mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties, 'text-decoration' is an animatable CSS property.

But I tried animating it via the transition property:

```js
function strikeText() {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.textdiv');
  const current = elem.style.textDecoration;
  elem.style.textDecoration = (  current == ""   ?  "line-through" : ""  );
}

function changeOpacity() {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.textdiv');
  const current = elem.style.opacity;
  elem.style.opacity = (  current == "0"   ?  "1" : "0"  );
}
```

```css
.textdiv {
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="textdiv">some text</div>

<button onclick="strikeText()">strikeText</button>
<button onclick="changeOpacity()">changeOpacity</button>
```

and while the opacity transition seems to work, the text-decoration transition isn't.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate just the part of text-decoration: text-decoration-color.

```css
.text {
  transition: text-decoration 2s ease;
  text-decoration: solid underline transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 .text:hover {
    text-decoration-color: #f95ce4;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text">hello world</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that only the text-decoration-color part is animatable. Under 'specification' in the official MDN site it says that the animated type is 'a color', as opposed to 'discrete' for things such as text-decoration-style. I guess this is one way to tell if something is animatable or not.

Answer (score 1):

text-decoration is not one of the properties that can be animated at all, including transitions

you can read the full article [here](https://markrabey.com/2015/05/17/css-transition-for-text-decoration/)